# Turn Cyrilic text to lowers case

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to convert the text to `lowercase`, but it contains Cyrillic characters and remains `uppercase`.

RegEx sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/GFuZYc/1

How do I change the `replace` parameter to make it work?

The text is:

```
WWWWWWWWW
wwwwwWWWWWWWwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwww
ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ
ыыыыыыыыЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫыыыыыыыы
```

Find:

```
(\w+|[ыЁёА-я]+)
```

Replace:

```
\L$1
```

Result:

```
wwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwww
ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ
ыыыыыыыыЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫыыыыыыыы
```

Comment: `\L` and `\U` only affect ASCII letters. You can't use them with Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: It is not possible. Use other software, programming language, or if you need it in NPP, write a PythonScript plugin/script.

Comment: In java use String.replace("ы","\L$1");

or use this regex `([ыЁёА-я]+)` to find all cyrillic letters.and replace them